# How do I display entries 1 by 1?

Tags: entries, craft.entries

I need to display entries that contain an image, and a piece of text, on the home page of my website.

When someone clicks 'next', I would like it to go to the next entry (by post date) and display that entries image and text. I also need the user to be able to click on 'previous' (by post date again) and 'random'.

How do I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`getNext()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getNext) and [`getPrev()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getPrev) methods on your entry like this:

```
{% set params = craft.entries.section('yoursection').order('postDate asc') %}

{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(params) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(params) %}
{# to access url, I use #}
{{ prevEntry.url }}
{# to access title, I use #}
{{ prevEntry.title }}
```

NOTE: I've shamelessly pinched this code from the answer [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14755/best-way-to-access-getprev-and-getnext-asset-fields).

You need to setup the `params` variable so that it would create a list of entries which would include your current entry and the next/prev entries you expect. So include your ordering by `postDate` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about how to create a plugin from the [Craft docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/introduction), then you can create one with [Pluginfactory.io](http://Pluginfactory.io)

I'll reload the entries with javascript in my example since I don't like reloading the page every single time and ajax is the way to go in these days. You can achieve this without any javascript/php code with only twig but users would have to refresh and reload the entire page then.

First you need a Controller that loads your entry and return a template. You could as well increase your limit and show/hide the rest of the entries via javascript or css but since you asked for only one I'll provide the code to only show one.

```
public function actionSearchEntry()
{
    $offset = craft()->request->getParam('offset');
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->section = "news";
    $criteria->orderBy = "postDate";
    $criteria->limit = 1;
    $criteria->offset = $offset;
    $entries = $criteria->find();
    $template = '';
    // to let your javascript know if it was successfuly
    $success = false;
    if($entries){
        $template = craft()->templates->render('path/to/your/template', array(
            'entry' => $entries[0]
        ));
        $success = true;
    }else{
        // render some not found template or search again to show the first one or so
    }
    $this->returnJson([
        'html'      => $template,
        'success'   => $success
    ]);
}
```

And this is your javascript file

```
var offset = 0;
$("#reloadButtonClick").change(function(){
    offset++;
    var data = {
        action: "pluginname/controllerName/searchEntry",
        offset: offset
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '',
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.success === true){
                $("#idOfYourDiv").html(data.html);
            }else{
                // display some errors or so
                offset = 0;
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
            console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

When you want to "scroll" to the previous entry you have to decrease your offset at some point.
Note: this is just a very basic example to show you the direction, I did not include much error handling you should to that on your own

Comment: I am needing an 'endless loop' through my entries for a kiosk application, and was wondering if this approach would work for that?  I had been using just Twig on a template, cycling through my selected entries with Javascript, but after running the loop for several hours, it crashes with a 500 error (incomplete load/timeout).  It always loads incomplete at a different place in the load.  Thanks for any leads.

Comment: I would suggest you to create a new question for this as it's more complicate to answer.. Furthermore this is for Craft 2 and I'm sure you are running a Craft 3 instance as of now

Comment: Thanks.  It's a Craft 2 site I inherited.  Here's my new question: https://tinyurl.com/4y726svw.